# How to redirect link in php code

Tags: php

I'm newbie in PHP.I got this code.

```
<?
$connection=mysql_connect("","","");
if(!$connection)
{
    die("Database Connection Failed: " . mysql_error());
}
//Select a database to use
$db=mysql_select_db('vss',$connection);
if(!$db)
{
    die("Database Selection Failed: " . mysql_error());
}

$class=$_POST['class'];
$section=$_POST['section'];
$roll=$_POST['roll'];
mysql_query("INSERT INTO student_class SET
            class='$class',
            section='$section',
            roll='$roll'");
print"Data Saved";//If data saved,I want to redirect link to a another page
mysql_close();
?>
```

==================================================================================

If data saved,I want to redirect link to a another page.is this possible??

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
$qry = mysql_query("INSERT INTO student_class(class, section, roll) VALUES('$class', '$section','$roll')", $connection);
if($qry){
   header("Location: nextPage.php");
   exit();
}else{
   echo "Inserting data fail. <hr />".mysql_error();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Where you have

```
print "Data saved";
```

Send a Location header to tell the browser to go to a different URL

```
header("Location: http://www.example.com/");
```

While you're making changes, [escape the user input](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) so that when [Little Bobby Tables](http://xkcd.com/327/) registers, it doesn't break your database.

Answer (score 0):

```
header('Location: http://www.php.net');
```

Comment: Please make sure that no html content is output (example: echo 'Hi' ) before making the header() call, or header() won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Yes

```
header("Location: new-url");
```

Note that this will only work if you have not emitted output before you get to the header.